# Is it possible to use spring-data-rest-webmvc without an actual Repository?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-rest

The question may sound funny but I think this should be possible.

What I want is to use a repository that is purely custom but is exposed just like a Repository. This service would have methods to get, save, delete and list objects where the data could be from any arbitrary source.

Looking through the code, I think it should be possible since methods are accessed using `CrudMethods` and `RepositoryInvoker`. I belief this requires an implementation of `RepositoryFactoryInformation` that will be discovered by `Repositories`. I started experimenting a bit and it looks like a full-blown spring-data-noop module.

Am I on the right track or is there an easier way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

I've ended up writing [spring-data-custom](https://github.com/molindo/spring-data-custom) to create fully customized spring-data repositories, allowing custom code to be used with spring-data-rest etc.

1. Enable custom repositories (`@EnableCustomRepositories`)
2. Annotate eligible entities (`@Custom`)
3. Create a repository (extend `CustomRepository<T, ID>`)
4. Add [custom behavior](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour):

   1. Let repository extend a new interface with the `Custom` suffix
   2. Create an implementation of the new interface with the `Impl` prefix
   3. Add one or more CRUD methods named `findOne`, `save`, `findAll`, `delete` (see `DefaultCrudMethods`)
   4. Add query methods annotated with `@Query`
5. Export repository using `spring-data-rest`

(copied from [README](https://github.com/molindo/spring-data-custom/blob/master/README.md))

As @wwadge correctly mentioned, [spring-data-keyvalue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-keyvalue) is an alternative. Repositories have to implement [KeyValueAdapter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-keyvalue/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/keyvalue/core/KeyValueAdapter.java), e.g. [MapKeyValueAdapter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-keyvalue/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/map/MapKeyValueAdapter.java).

Comment: Sprign data keyvalue is just unbeliavebl

Answer (score 2):

The easier way is to use spring-data-keyvalue project which does what you are trying to do.