# Implement a custom Spring Data Repository for a non-supported database

Tags: spring, spring-data

I want to implement a Spring Data Repository for a database which is not currentlty supported (hyphothetical question - no need to ask about the database).

How is this possible and where can I have an example of that?

Comment: Spring Data haven't relation to db support. It's just one addition abstraction layer over ORM technologies, like Hibernate, EclipseLink or something else.

Comment: I am asking for documentation/tutorial in order to implement the pretty same type of abstraction for another database which already has a java toolset.

Comment: sounds a lot like this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554297/is-it-possible-to-use-spring-data-rest-webmvc-without-an-actual-repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is "yes, definitely". One of the main Spring-data's intentions is to unify access to different data storage technologies under same API style. So you can implement spring-data adapter for any database as long as it is worth implementing a connector to that database in Java (which is definitely possible for the majority of databases).

Long answer would take several blog posts or even a small book :-) But let me just highlight couple of moments. Each of the existing spring-data modules expose one of (or both) the API flavors:

- imperative - in a form of various template classes (e.g. [RedisTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/RedisTemplate.html)). It is mostly for the databases that don't have query language, but only a programmatic API. So you're just wrapping your db's API into template class and you're done.
- declarative - in a form of so called [Declarative Repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories), quite sophisticated mechanism of matching annotations on method signatures or method signatures themselves to a db's native queries. Luckily spring-data-commons module provides a lot of scaffolding and common infrastructure code for this, so you just need to fill the gaps for your specific data storage mechanism. You can look at [slide deck](https://www.slideshare.net/maksym_govorischev/jeeconf-2018-the-anatomy-of-spring-data) from my conference talk, where I explained on a high level the mechanics of how particular spring-data module generates real implementations of repositories based on user declarations. Or you can just go into any of the existing modules and look into source code. The most interesting parts there are  usually RepositoryFactory and QueryLookupStrategy implementations.

That is extremely simplified view of the spring-data concepts. In order to get more detailed information and explanations of core principles, I'd suggest reading [spring-data-commons](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/) reference documentation and having a look at [spring-data-keyvalue](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/keyvalue/docs/1.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/) project, which is a good starting point to implement Spring Data Module for key-value storages.